# 1 liner regex to get everything before semi colon

Tags: nintex-workflow

I have this variable 1874;#Bob Williams. I tried this and it should give me 1874 but it's giving me the entire variable. Any idea?

```
(?<=\w+;)
```

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/pA3pR8/1) shows that your regex works correctly.  It's possible that it's a .NET specific issue, but are you positive that its the regex and not another problem in your code?

Comment: Please show all of your code. Also, if you want a regex, you might want to use the tag "regex", plus the language tag of the language which you would expect answers to be in.

Comment: You've tagged `.net`, but that looks like a JavaScript regex literal. In either case, your input is too simple to bother with regex. Also, your regex is a greedy match for anything except `;` so it's giving you 2 matches rather than the entire string, first `1874`, second `#Bob Williams`.

Comment: Actually, I am using Nintex workflow (which is based on .net c#). Although, it's working per Hill's link , I am not sure why Nintex is not respecting the Regex.

Comment: Try removing the `/` from your regex pattern. i.e. try with `([^;]+)`

Comment: @SaebAmini: I updated the original post with different regex but that one does not work either. I tried your and the result is semicolon only. I just need everything before semicolon. We should be able to use these regex https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: (^.*?(?=;)) gives me semicolon and everything after. so it looks like ;#Bob Williams.  This (^([^;]*);) gives me #Bob Williams.

Comment: Your updated regex is just a zero-width assertion (a positive look-behind), it doesn't match anything.

Comment: It looks like Nintex or whatever crazy thing you're using is returning inverse results, so this should work for you! `;.+`

Comment: @NinjaCowgirl Can you share a complete snippet to showcase your use?

Comment: @SaebAmini: ;.+ worked like charm. Thanks. Can you post an answer with this code so I can mark complete. Thanks

Comment: @NinjaCowgirl Haha OK! yw :)

Comment: The correct way to do this in .NET would be either `.*;` or `[^;]*;` optionally using `+` instead of `*`. If you have to do "the opposite" in Nintext workflow, then this is not .NET. I edited the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever tool/engine you're using is *removing* what it matches and returns what *remains* after removal, so this should work for you: `;.+`

Answer (score 1):

A bit off topic but you dont need a regex for this. Not at all. Use `Substring`instead:

```
var s = "1874;#Bob Williams";
s = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(';')); // If your input might not contain a semi colon, check the return of IndexOf
// s == "1874"
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ug6Hwl)

If you are writing `.NET` code as your tag show, use this.

Comment: Thanks for pitching in. I was really looking for one liner.

Comment: `s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(';'));` is a one-liner.